# Using Q promises - is there a way to make this code less repetitive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, q

I'm starting an integration test suite for my Node.js app.  I'm currently trying to write a setup script that wipes the test database and populates it with some test data.  I'm trying to avoid the dreaded ["Pyramid of Doom"](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/13-03-28/what-is-the-point-of-promises), and I was hoping to use promises as a way of preventing my code from getting out of hand. I'm very new to promises, and I'm still trying to wrap my head around them - it's possible I'm not using them correctly.

Here is my initial version without promises. This works, but has nested callbacks up the wazoo:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./user');
var MONGODB_URL = process.env.MONGODB_TEST_URL || 'localhost:27017/swot_test';

console.log('\nRunning e2e test preparation script');
console.log('-----------------------------------\n');

console.log('Connecting to database:', MONGODB_URL, '...')
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URL, function () {

    console.log('Wiping database...')
    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function () {

        console.log('Setting up test user...')
        User.createUser({
            email: 'test@example.com',
            password: 'tester'
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // If there was more setup, it would have to go here... pyramid of doom!

            console.log('Finished.');
            process.exit();
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a version that uses [Q promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q):

```
var Q = require('q');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./user');
var MONGODB_URL = process.env.MONGODB_TEST_URL || 'localhost:27017/swot_test';

console.log('\nRunning e2e test preparation script');
console.log('-----------------------------------\n');

Q.fcall(function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('Connecting to database:', MONGODB_URL, '...');
    mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URL, function (err) {
        if (err) deferred.reject(new Error(err));
        else deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
})
.then(function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('Wiping database...');
    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function (err) {
        if (err) deferred.reject(new Error(err));
        else deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
})
.then(function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('Setting up test user...');
    User.createUser({
        email: 'test@example.com',
        password: 'tester'
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) deferred.reject(new Error(err));
        else deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
})
.done(function () {
    console.log('Finished.');
    process.exit();
}, function (err) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err.stack);
});
```

I like that it has less nesting, but there's a lot of repetition in there. Is there a way I could use the helper functions in the [Q API](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) to make this code more concise and less repetitive?  Especially this part:

```
if (err) deferred.reject(new Error(err));
else deferred.resolve();
```

I would appreciate any help with cleaning up this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Q.ninvoke(mongoose,'connect', MONGODB_URL)
 .then(function () {
    console.log('Wiping database...');
    return Q.ninvoke(mongoose.connection.db, 'dropDatabase');
 })
 .then(function () {
    console.log('Setting up test user...')
    return Q.ninvoke(User, 'createUser', {
        email: 'test@example.com',
        password: 'tester'
    });
 })
 .then(function (user) {
    console.log('Finished.');
    process.exit();
 })
 .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly shorten it with reusable `oncomplete` helper like this:

```
function oncomplete(deferred) {
    return function (err, result) {
        if (err) deferred.reject(new Error(err));
        else deferred.resolve(result);
    }
}

Q.fcall(function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('Connecting to database:', MONGODB_URL, '...');
    mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URL, oncomplete(deferred));
    return deferred.promise;
})
.then(function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('Wiping database...');
    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(oncomplete(deferred));
    return deferred.promise;
})
.then(function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('Setting up test user...');
    User.createUser({
        email: 'test@example.com',
        password: 'tester'
    }, oncomplete(deferred));
    return deferred.promise;
})
.done(function () {
    console.log('Finished.');
    process.exit();
}, function (err) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err.stack);
});
```

If you're brave enough, you can drastically simplify it with [Node v0.11 beta and `yield`](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/how-yield-will-transform-node) keyword. That would implement an asynchronous state machine, so you could have pseudo-liner code flow without explicit callbacks.

Comment: **@down-voter:** please leave a comment, so we all can learn what part of my answer is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the `async` module, specifically `waterfall`. You can read about it here:

https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback

Basically it allows you to chain a set of nested callbacks in a nice and concise manner.

Comment: Any reason why this was down voted? It is a perfect way to clean up the code above.

Comment: I don't think there is a reason. I did a minor edit to your answer, this gives the person who down-voted it a chance to undo that, if he/she did it by mistake.

Comment: Async isn't really promise-based. That makes this kinda downvotable I think. The question was about "Using Q promises".